# Barcode API for Windows Phone and iOS similar to Android Mobile Vision existing?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, android-vision

I have created an android app using the relatively new Android Mobile Vision API (https://developers.google.com/vision/). I was wondering if you guys know if there is a similar API, which also detects multiple barcodes (and faces in best case) in a live view at the same time and keeps scanning even though codes where found, for Windows Phone and iOS.

Hope somebody has an idea.

Cheers

Comment: Technically, http://www.scandit.com/ has a cross-platform barcode SDK..